# What is the equivalent of "good honors degree" in terms of universities in EU

Tags: masters, application, terminology

The requirements for applying for a master's programme in National University of Singapore are stated as

> The candidates must possess:
>
> - A good honours degree in computing; or
> - A good honours degree in a related discipline with 2 years IT industry experience; or
> - A good bachelor's degree in computing with 2 years IT industry experience; or
> - A good bachelor's or honours degree in business related discipline    with 2 years IT industry experience.

In my country, a student is considered as an *honorable student* if he/she completes his/her education with a GPA over 3.00/4.00 but I don't know what is a **good** honour degree?

I have looked it up on Google but there are a lot of different definitions.
Also, I could not find any statements in the university website. Can you help me?

Comment: It has been said here numerous times (and I guess it will be said even more) but there is no one admission policy generally accepted in the EU. Countries and indeed universities in the same country might have different requirements. I have never heard of an "honor's degree" in Sweden, and sounds rather silly to my ears, if your grades/GPA matter, they just ask your transcript of records.

Comment: It does not matter if there is any honor's degree or not. I just wonder what is **good honour** in Singapore? Is it about cumulative average grade or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For historical reasons, Singapore often uses the U.K degree classification system.   'Good Honours Degree' usually means either 'First class Honours' or 'Upper Second Class Honours'.   These map (approximately) onto the U.S 'cum laude' classifications.

For more info, see Wikipedia 'British undergraduate degree classification'.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably not a general equivalent (EU is not a monolithic block). For instance, in my country, Italy, the nearest equivalent is probably that of the *Laurea a pieni voti* (roughly "graduated with full marks"), which means a grade between 99/110 and 109/110 (in Italy MsC grades range from 66 to 110 *cum laude*).

Years ago to apply for certain positions in Italy, especially in the public administration, it was required to have a *laurea a pieni voti*, but I haven't seen such a requirement for years and it was more spread in the humanities.

In any case students from European universities can ask to their universities the so called [Diploma Supplement](http://ec.europa.eu/education/tools/diploma-supplement_en.htm), a document which should help the international recognition of the qualifications. This document should provide information on the local grading system and report the corresponding student's grades in the [ECTS grading scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECTS_grading_scale).

Maybe if you look at the [ECTS User's Guide](http://ec.europa.eu/education/tools/docs/ects-guide_en.pdf) you can find information on what can be an equivalent to the *good honor's degree*.